# How to draw lines with different thicknesses in CoreGraphic in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I draw grids with CoreGraphic in iOS (as shown below). But for some lines, I'd like to change line thickness. How can I change line thickness in CoreGraphic?

```
//Get the CGContext from this view
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Set the stroke (pen) color
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    //Set the width of the pen mark
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

    //Draw vertical lines
    float max = totalVerticalLines*numskipPixels_h+orgx;

    for(float i = orgx; i <= max; i+=numskipPixels_h){

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, i, orgy);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, i, orgy - verLineLength);

    }


    //Draw vertical lines
    float min = orgy - totalHorLines*numskipPixels_v;
    for(float i = orgy; i > min; i-=numskipPixels_v){
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, orgx, i);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, orgx+horLineLength, i);
    }

//Draw it
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: Use `CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);` just as you're doing in your code already but with a different number for the `1.0`. What is the exact problem you are having? What is the expected output and what are you actually getting?

Comment: Some lines I like to draw with CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);. But some lines I like to draw with CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0); Now the problem is I can choose either one only. Are you the one down voted? You know how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create different paths for the different thicknesses, change the thickness between calls to CGContextStrokePath.

Like so:

```
float min = orgy - totalHorLines*numskipPixels_v;
for(float i = orgy; i > min; i-=numskipPixels_v){
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, orgx, i);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, orgx+horLineLength, i);
}

//Draw it
CGContextStrokePath(context);

//Set the width of the pen mark to a different value
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5.0);

//start a new path
CGContextBeginPath(context);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point1x, point1y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point2x, point2y);

//Draw the new path (uses the new line thickness)
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```